# How can I solve a memory leak problem in Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory-leaks, heap-dump

I'm currently working on sending push messages using nodejs.
I sent a push message to roughly 10,000 people but there was a problem with my code.
The code to send the push message is in the screenshot below.
[image]

The pushSend method is called 10000 to 20000 times.
The problem is a memory leak after sending a push message.
I analyzed a heap dump to solve the problem. Meanwhile, I found the following result. But for now I'm not sure why this problem happened.
[image]

Comment: Are you creating a new FCM object for every one of the 20,000 times you execute this code?  Are you sure the server is up and reachable because this FCM code has code to do exponential backup automatic retries if the server is not immediately reachable which would keep a lot of requests in flight at the same time if you kept calling it over and over again while the server was not reachable?

Comment: um..It does not create a new new FCM Object every time.
I make 20000 calls using a single fcm object.

Comment: Well, there's nothing in the code you show that seems like it would leak by itself. So, if it's really this code causing a leak, then it has to be inside of `fcm.send()`.  And, in the code for the [fcm-push](https://github.com/nandarustam/fcm-push/blob/master/lib/fcm.js), module, the only potential leak I spy there is if the send operation gets in a retry loop where that will keep a lot of state in memory until the retry is finally done.

Comment: I agree with you. When I analyzed the heapdump entirely, there was a memory leak in the method inside fcm.send ().

And now I solved this problem. Instead of calling send () multiple times with a single FCM object, Fixed a memory leak when calling the send method each time creating a new fcm object.(     new FCM ().send (push_data, (err, response) => {}
) .....  )

But I still don't know why calling the send method several times with a single FCM object caused that problem.

thank you for the reply.

Comment: What exactly inside that method was leaking?

Comment: I'm not sure yet.
The source code inside fcm.send () is very complicated. I think I should study a little more.